# Link to a specific step in onepage checkout

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Is it possible to redirect the browser to nth step in the onepage checkout? If so, how would one go about doing it?

I'm working on a payment module and have a sort of "cancel" action that i would like to return the user to the step in checkout where you choose the payment method.

I currently return the user to the first step of the checkout like so:

```
$this->_redirect('checkout/onepage', array('_secure'=>true));
```

Another issue with this is that i does not work all the time, in certain browsers i'd really not like to name this sort of works "sometimes". Is that something that is known and/or commonly accepted? I have very little actual information regarding this, but i've had complaints from customers about this behaviour. They generally won't give me any specifics so it's kind of a dead end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### checkout/onepage.phtml:

**In PHP**

```
$step = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('step');
$stepCodes = array('billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');

if (($step) && (in_array($step,$stepCodes)) && ($this->getActiveStep() == 'billing')) {
    $checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage');
    $checkout->saveBilling(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->toArray(),false);
    $checkout->saveShipping(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->toArray(),false);
    $checkout->saveShippingMethod(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod());
    $activestep = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('step');
}
else 
if($this->getActiveStep()) {
    $activestep = $this->getActiveStep();
}
```

**In javascript**

```
accordion.openSection('opc-<?php /* edit */ echo $activestep; ?>');
```

Comment: I do suspect that loading the checkout could be simplified considering that the customer already has a quote prepared. But this is the way that i got it to work. If anyone can improve from it, please!

Comment: Hi @Peter Lindqvist, have you found another solution? If not could you explain a little more about this solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for not being clear. Open the template for the onepage checkout page. 
It is app/design/frontend/default/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml 
In the file add

```
<?php 
//if (your cancel condition) 
{ 
echo 
'<script type="text/javascript"> 
checkout.gotoSection(\'checkout-step-review\'); 
</script>'; 
}
?>
```

This will take the user the to the step you need. You have to decide the condition(s) under which the user is taken to the step.

Comment: Not sure i follow you there.. Could you explain?

Comment: What page are you referring to, and how do i do that in the controller that redirects to the checkout page?

Comment: this alone did not work. i also had to load the different steps and save the data.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do the same thing, but couldn't figure out how to make the one page checkout open at the payment step.

In the end, I used jQuery and an ajax call so I could call javascript code after changing the page:

```
    jQuery('body').load(failure, {}, function () {
        // set the magento onepage checkout accordion to the payment section
        checkout.gotoSection('payment');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Rick is referring to the fact the 'steps' in the checkout are a not RESTful, but Ajaxified steps, they are all on the same page, the vertical accordion is, in fact, just a set of divisions manipulated by a javascript function. You'll need to set the javascript to the proper step as he stated.

Comment: It sounds as if there is no "standardized" way to land the user on a certain step. Is that a correct assumption?