# Magento skip two steps in checkout

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.6

When guest user has already added addresses, I have to move from step 1 (select checkout method) to shipping method step. I have tried following code in overrided class Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage in method saveCheckoutMethod. However this is not working, guest goes to Billing Address step, but message "Setting step shipping_method." is printed to Magento log. Is there any way to go directly to shipping method step and skip two address steps programmatically?

```
public function saveCheckoutMethod($method)
{
    if (empty($method)) {
        return array('error' => -1, 'message' => $this->_helper->__('Invalid data.'));
    }

    $this->getQuote()->setCheckoutMethod($method)->save();

    $quote = $this->getQuote();
    if($quote->getBillingAddress()->validate() && $quote->getShippingAddress()->validate())
    {           
        $this->getCheckout()
            ->setStepData('billing', 'complete', false)
            ->setStepData('shipping', 'complete', false)
            ->setStepData('shipping_method', 'allow', true);
        Mage::log("Setting step shipping_method.");
    }
    else 
    {
        $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('billing', 'allow', true);
    }

    return array();
}
```

Comment: Go with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718293/link-to-a-specific-step-in-onepage-checkout. To preserve the checkout step, use cookie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveBillingAction()` method, there is an example how can you jump to another step (it skips shipping address step)

```
} elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
    // Here you can specify step name
    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';

    $result['update_section'] = array(
        'name' => 'shipping-method',
        'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
    );

    $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
    $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
```

Comment: I tried that, but i doesn't seem to work in method Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveMethodAction(), it goes to next step (billing address) instead of shipping method. I have checked that overriding controller is actually run by adding logging lines to overriding controller.