# How can I return to the onepage checkout in a specific step?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, checkout, magento-1.8

I am making a payment method but I have to make a redirection before the order is placed so I am using the getCheckoutUrlRedirect() method to achieve this, with these I can check that the user enters the correct data and I have the authorization from the bank to charge them, the thing is that when they return from the webpage I need to take them to the Review step in the checkout so the customer click to complete the order and in this moment charge his credit card or if the authorization failed return them to the payment step in the checkout.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718293/link-to-a-specific-step-in-onepage-checkout

Comment: I have read it but it didn't work for me and well I didn't quite get the solution, if you have another please let me know @seanbreeden